# How to sync data from Elasticsearch to Memgraph as nodes and relationships

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm looking for a way to synchronize my data from Elasticsearch into Memgraph to represent it as nodes and relationships.  I've found blog post that talks about something similar (https://memgraph.com/blog/synchronize-data-between-memgraph-graph-database-and-elasticsearch). It is about syncing data from Memgraph to Elasticsearch, but I'm currently looking for a method to achieve the reverse: syncing data from Elasticsearch to Memgraph.

What should be my starting point for this?